# How to debug intermittent Error 500 error in domlogs?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website running in my own dedicated server running CPANEL. 
I have Apache/2.4.12 and PHP Version 5.4.41.

Once in a while I see error 500 response in the log. But I couldn't seem to figure out where it's coming from. When I check the page... it is fine and throws 200 response code. When I try to fetch it in Google, it's also fine. But sometimes, Google Webmasters will report I got Error 500 in some of the pages.

Anyone here have gone through properly debugging this? What might be triggering the error?

Example from the log:

```
46.229.168.79 - - [16/Mar/2018:09:45:04 -0400] "GET /sports-nfl-larry-allen-weight HTTP/1.1" 500 6935 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
148.64.56.65 - - [16/Mar/2018:09:45:09 -0400] "GET /snap-meee HTTP/1.1" 500 6711 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GrapeshotCrawler/2.0; +http://www.grapeshot.co.uk/crawler.php)"
23.96.208.137 - - [16/Mar/2018:11:30:05 -0400] "GET /rihanna-slams-snapchat HTTP/1.1" 500 7462 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)"
72.30.14.91 - - [16/Mar/2018:11:30:07 -0400] "HEAD /kendall-jenner-explained-to-ellen-degeneres HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
```

Just to add more info. I got APC caching and I use a CDN provider. But like I said, the page actually responds pretty quick with no error when I check it.

EDIT: Something from error log.. but I don't see any log corresponding to the timestamp when Error 500's occur.

```
[Thu Mar 15 17:12:44.532038 2018] [core:error] [pid 26532] [client 194.0.200.11:52727] AH00135: Invalid method in request ------41184676334--
[Thu Mar 15 17:13:01.113257 2018] [core:error] [pid 26538] [client 194.0.200.11:54514] AH00135: Invalid method in request ------41184676334--
[Thu Mar 15 20:10:44.220358 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17916] AH00052: child pid 8905 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Mar 16 05:35:21.280659 2018] [core:error] [pid 25310] [client 71.6.146.185:57523] AH00135: Invalid method in request quit
[Fri Mar 16 08:25:10.126197 2018] [:error] [pid 6358] [client 66.249.69.147:43415] script '/home/****/public_html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Mar 16 12:25:22.897389 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17916] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Mar 16 12:25:22.950624 2018] [mpm_prefork:warn] [pid 17916] AH00181: MaxRequestWorkers of 400 exceeds ServerLimit value of 256, decreasing to match
[Fri Mar 16 12:25:23.001101 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 17916] AH01909: proxy-subdomains-ssl-default-vhost.localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 16 12:25:23.138917 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17916] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.41 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 16 12:25:23.138948 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17916] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd'
```

I'm currently fixing the MaxRequestWorkers warning which I think has nothing to do with the Error 500.

Comment: Check your server error logs. It's usually found in `/var/log/httpd/` or `/var/log/apache2/` If you can't find them, you may need to contact your host.

Comment: I run my own server... and I already checked those logs. My last option is to ask here... because I can't see the culprit from the log. Unless I'm missing some areas to look at.

Comment: You're showing the access log. Do you have anything from the error log? Make sure that you don't have the error log disabled in the Apache config (usually set per site). The logs often have `error` in the name.

Comment: I wonder if it's the [ssl:warn] from the log...

Comment: It could be. The `script '/home/****/public_html/index.php' not found or unable to stat` is interesting, you may need to double-check the paths and the config. Unless you fixed that before the restart (SIGHUP)

Comment: that error is from trying to stat a new site on the server... the error 500 was from a different site... anyhow i will fix all other errors. I think that one is self explanatory,

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally!!! I changed my error_reporting to...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Now I saw the error on the page itself

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

For some reason... the site renders just fine and returns 200 response when I check it manually and when the error reporting was originally set to E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR

This bug has cost me a lot of traffic. I've been wondering why some of my page has been dropped from Google search. Now I know why...

Thanks.